# How to find out who has published a post using my OG action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have an open graph action that has finally been approved and is active on my app now. Is there any way to track who publishes a post using my OG action from within my app?

Here is the code I'm using for my action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function postEndorse()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/namespace:endorse',
        'post',
        { photo: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>' },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error Occurred' + response + " " + response.error);
           } else {
              alert('Thank you!');
           }
        });
  }
  </script>
```

I am requesting the publish_actions permissions when people log in.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response in your JavaScript code above has the id of the action.

```
{
  id: “{action-instance-id}”
}
```

You need to store your actions via database or otherwise. Once you have that you can make a call against it

```
/action-instance-id?fields=from.fields(id)
```

Which will give a response such as

```
{
  "from": {
    "id": "{user-id}"
  }, 
  "id": "{action-instance-id}"
}
```

There are many ways to store this data, one way would be AJAX to PHP/MySQL.
I suggest reading up on it. **The following hasn't been tested, just gives an idea of how to send the data across. Think of it as pseudocode**

Add jQuery to the `<head>`

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Send the `id` of the user, like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function postEndorse()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/namespace:endorse',
        'post',
        { photo: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>' },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error Occurred' + response + " " + response.error);
           } else {
              FB.api(
                response.id + "?fields=from.fields(id)",
                 function(resp) {
                     if (!resp || resp.error) {
                        alert('Error Occurred' + resp + " " + resp.error);
                      } else {
                        $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "fbdata.php",
                           data: { id: resp.from.id, actionid: resp.id }
                        }).done(function( msg ) {
                           alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                        });
                     }
              });
           }
        });
  }
  </script>
```

Then in fbdata.php something like

```
<?php

include("database.inc.php");
mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$actionid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['actionid']);

$database_entry = "INSERT INTO Actions (Id, Action) VALUES ('$id', '$actionid') ;
mysql_query($database_ntry) or die(mysql_error());


mysql_close();
?>
```

References that you should read

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php

Comment: Thanks phwd for the response. This is the bit I am unsure about. How do I store this data? I understand how to get the id in the alert response but I've no idea how to retrieve this id and then get it into the database. Sorry, I know that's a big task but I need to learn how to do this. Are you able to point me in the right direction? Thanks D

Comment: @DamienDoherty I placed some pseudo code above that gives an idea of how things work but you should really read up on it. There is a lot of reference information already available out there.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you change 
`/me/namespace:endorse` to `/users facebook id/namespace:endorse` Then you can store the facebook id of the person and then track them back using that.

Comment: Thanks Wesley.That's exactly what I would like to do. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that. I was hoping there would be somewhere within facebook to do this. Are you able to help me out / point me in the right direction? Even a link to a tutorial would be a help. Many thanks. D